# JavaScript: What are .extend and .prototype used for?

Tags: javascript, prototype, object-model

I am relatively new to JavaScript and keep seeing .extend and .prototype in third party libraries I am using. I thought it had to do with the Prototype javascript library, but I am beginning to think that is not the case. What are these used for?

Comment: if you want to learn more about this prototype stuff i recommend on khan academy   https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming/object-oriented/pt/object-inheritance

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Javascript's inheritance is prototype based, so you extend the prototypes of objects such as Date, Math, and even your own custom ones.

```
Date.prototype.lol = function() {
 alert('hi');
};

( new Date ).lol() // alert message
```

In the snippet above, I define a method for *all* Date objects ( already existing ones and all new ones ).

`extend` is usually a high level function that copies the prototype of a new subclass that you want to extend from the base class.

So you can do something like:

```
extend( Fighter, Human )
```

And the `Fighter` constructor/object will inherit the prototype of `Human`, so if you define methods such as `live` and `die` on `Human` then `Fighter` will also inherit those.

Updated Clarification:

"high level function" meaning .extend isn't built-in but often provided by a library such as jQuery or Prototype.

Comment: "high level function" meaning `.extend` isn't built-in but often provided by a library such as jQuery or Prototype.

Comment: I would add it's not suggested to extend the prototypes of native objects in JS

Comment: @meder - you should add visum comment in your answer. :)

Comment: In modern Javascript programming, it's customary to treat globals and native objects like elements of a public bathroom; you can't avoid going in there, but you should try to minimize contact with surfaces.  This is because `changing the native objects can break other developer's assumptions of these objects,` leading to javascript bugs which can often cost many hours to tracking down.  The leading sentence on this answer seems to misrepresent this valuable javascript practice.

Answer (score 25):

`.extend()` is added by many third-party libraries to make it easy to create objects from other objects.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/ or http://www.prototypejs.org/api/object/extend for some examples.

`.prototype` refers to the "template" (if you want to call it that) of an object, so by adding methods to an object's prototype (you see this a lot in libraries to add to String, Date, Math, or even Function) those methods are added to every new instance of that object.

Answer (score 19):

The `extend` method for example in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) or [PrototypeJS](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/object/extend), copies all properties from the source to the destination object.

Now about the `prototype` property, it is a member of function objects, it is part of the language core.

Any function can be used as a [*constructor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_Constructor_Function), to create new object instances. All functions have this `prototype` property.

When you use the `new` operator with on a function object, a new object will be created, and it will inherit from its constructor `prototype`.

For example:

```
function Foo () {
}
Foo.prototype.bar = true;

var foo = new Foo();

foo.bar; // true
foo instanceof Foo; // true
Foo.prototype.isPrototypeOf(foo); // true
```

Answer (score 18):

Javascript inheritance seems to be like an open debate everywhere. It can be called "The curious case of Javascript language".

The idea is that there is a base class and then you extend the base class to get an inheritance-like feature (not completely, but still).

The whole idea is to get what prototype really means. I did not get it until I saw John Resig's code (close to what `jQuery.extend` does) wrote a code chunk that does it and he claims that base2 and prototype libraries were the source of inspiration.

Here is the code.

```
    /* Simple JavaScript Inheritance
     * By John Resig http://ejohn.org/
     * MIT Licensed.
     */  
     // Inspired by base2 and Prototype
    (function(){
  var initializing = false, fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;

  // The base Class implementation (does nothing)
  this.Class = function(){};

  // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
  Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super = this.prototype;

    // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
    // don't run the init constructor)
    initializing = true;
    var prototype = new this();
    initializing = false;

    // Copy the properties over onto the new prototype
    for (var name in prop) {
      // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
      prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" &&
        typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name]) ?
        (function(name, fn){
          return function() {
            var tmp = this._super;

            // Add a new ._super() method that is the same method
            // but on the super-class
            this._super = _super[name];

            // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we
            // remove it when we're done executing
            var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);        
            this._super = tmp;

            return ret;
          };
        })(name, prop[name]) :
        prop[name];
    }

    // The dummy class constructor
    function Class() {
      // All construction is actually done in the init method
      if ( !initializing && this.init )
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // Populate our constructed prototype object
    Class.prototype = prototype;

    // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
    Class.prototype.constructor = Class;

    // And make this class extendable
    Class.extend = arguments.callee;

    return Class;
  };
})();
```

There are three parts which are doing the job. First, you loop through the properties and add them to the instance. After that, you create a constructor for later to be added to the object.Now, the key lines are:

```
// Populate our constructed prototype object
Class.prototype = prototype;

// Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
```

You first point the `Class.prototype` to the desired prototype. Now, the whole object has changed meaning that you need to force the layout back to its own one.

And the usage example:

```
var Car = Class.Extend({
  setColor: function(clr){
    color = clr;
  }
});

var volvo = Car.Extend({
   getColor: function () {
      return color;
   }
});
```

Read more about it here at [Javascript Inheritance by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) 's post.

Answer (score 2):

Some `extend` functions in third party libraries are more complex than others. [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) for instance contains a minimally simple one that doesn't have some of the checks that jQuery's does:

```
function extend(target, source) {
    if (source) {
        for(var prop in source) {
            if(source.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                target[prop] = source[prop];
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `.extends()`  create a class which is a child of another class.
   behind the scenes 
  `Child.prototype.__proto__` sets its value to `Parent.prototype` 
   so methods are inherited.
- `.prototype` inherit features from one to another.
- `.__proto__`  is a getter/setter for Prototype.

Comment: Should this not be .extend() and *not* .extends() ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the clearest and simplest example to me, this just appends property or replaces existing.

```
function replaceProperties(copyTo, copyFrom)  {
  for (var property in copyFrom) 
    copyTo[property] =  copyFrom[property]
  return copyTo
}
```