# How to add missing JavaScript functions to all Strings in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, trim

I need the `trim()` function in IE8 but it's only available in IE9. How do I add it myself to IE8? I've heard of shimming or something similar but how does it work?

I'm currently writing this code:

```
var trim = String.trim || function (str) {
    return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}
```

But then I need to replace all `str_variable.trim()` with `trim(str_variable)`. How else can I write `trim` function and add it to String?

Comment: change "var trim = String.trim ||" to "String.prototype.trim=". this is safe to do, but your regexp is slow and busted...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/javascript-add-method-to-string-class

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.trim = String.prototype.trim || function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}
```

however, I question if this covers the same functionality as the native method.

Better to use the [polyfill at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  (function(){  
    // Make sure we trim BOM and NBSP
    var rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;
    String.prototype.trim = function () {
      return this.replace(rtrim, "");
    }
  })();
}
```

Comment: @ŠimeVidas MDN is perfect. Always.