# Javascript custom method of str Object

Tags: javascript

iam new to JS so here's the question:
I want to make a method to string Object.
For example :

```
word = "Hello"
word1 = word.method() ->
word1 = "Hello123"
```

My method adds "123" to my str.
My thoughts:

```
function NewStr() {
this.method = function () { return NewStr + "123"};
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript: add method to string class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/javascript-add-method-to-string-class)

Comment: What's wrong with the function that you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add method

String.prototype.NewStr=  function () { return this + "123"};