# Execute function off of variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am quite newish at nodejs and javascript in general, and I have been trying to figure out how to make a function that executes on a variable, e.g.

```
var string = "Hello there";
var string1 = "Hello there again"
string = string.function();
string1 = string.function();
```

I am aware that this can be achieved by doing something like this `function(string);`, but I am a massive fan of more "inline code" and would like a nicer way to do it.

Comment: Not sure what you looking for, this? [javascript: add method to string class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/javascript-add-method-to-string-class)

Comment: Just a warning. Modifying the prototype of a Javascript Object that you don't own, such as String, can potentially lead to complications. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript: add method to string class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/javascript-add-method-to-string-class)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you make your string variable an object

```
var string = {
   text: "Hello there",
   func: function(value) {
       return value;
   }
}
string.func(string.text); // Hello there
```

Edit: If you want your function to work on all strings add a method in `String.prototype` like so

```
String.prototype.your_function = function (char) {
  // work on char here
  return char
};
```

Comment: Not sure if it was unclear, but I want it to be able to work on any and all strings. Like pythons, `string.format()`, which will work on any string

Comment: You can use `String.prototype` for that

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you need

```js
String.prototype.function = function ()
{
    return this + " world";
};
    
var x = "hello";
var y = x.function();
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom functions to built in JavaScript object prototypes to your need.

For example in the case of your string approach, you can add a custom property to `String.prototype` like this:

```
String.prototype.myFunction = function() {
    return 'Value from myFunction: ' + this.valueOf();
}
```

And when you declare a string you can go and call your new function inline:

```
var s = 'my string';
s.myFunction();
```

And it will return:

```
"Value from myFunction: my string"
```

Hope it helps!