# How in javascript to implement a function that is called as a string?

Tags: javascript, string, function, call

I need to implement a function that is called as a string, how to do this better?
An example of a call might look like this:

```
var a = ‘Hi’.myFunc();
console.log(a); // Hi
```

Comment: `var a = 'Hi'; console.log(a);`

Comment: do you want to add a custom string function

Comment: You want to add a method to `String.prototype`…? But then again, you don't need that if you just want `a` to be `'Hi'`…

Comment: You need to add a function to String.prototype. [Look it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/javascript-add-method-to-string-class), it should help

Comment: If you want to manipulate the string you can do something like this: http://jsbin.com/xacoyut/edit?js,console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String.prototype.myFunc= function(){
   return this.toString()
}

var a = 'Hi'.myFunc();
console.log(a); // Hi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution to attach a function to any String

```
String.prototype.coucou = function(){
 console.log("coucou")   
}

"a".coucou()  //print "coucou" in console
```