# Javascript custom functions with string

Tags: javascript

Today i was asked question in interview. when i call 'hello'.replicate(3) it should print 'hellohellohello'

please help if anyone has answer to this

```js
// 'hello'.replicate(3)
//output > 'hellohellohello'


function replicate(num){
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your effort? Also don't modify builtin object (string) behavior.

Comment: i tried bu ti am stuck how to pick string from external

Comment: "Pick string from external"? What does it mean?

Comment: 'helo' a string and attach function to it and get output. i never did this before and got stuck here

Comment: 'hello'.replicate(3)

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/javascript-add-method-to-string-class). You didn't research before asking, downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JavaScript string will inherit functions from its prototype, so you need to add the function to the string prototype.  For example:

```
String.prototype.replicate = function (n) {
  var replicatedString = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    replicatedString += this;
  }

  return replicatedString;
};
```

See also:

[javascript: add method to string class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/javascript-add-method-to-string-class)