# Javascript Function with String/Object attached to it

Tags: javascript, function

In javascript, I want to write a function which is called as follows:

```
var x = 'testString'
var y = 'anotherstring'
var z = 0

var result = x.aFunction(y, z)

function aFunction(y, z) {
  ...
}
```

This is the first time I am attempting this, my question is how can I get and use the value of **x** in the function **aFunction**, without actually referring to the declared variable.

I tried looking for this but I cannot find anything. If there is a post specifically for this that anyone knows about, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You want to make `aFunction` a string method?

Comment: Like? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/javascript-add-method-to-string-class

Comment: *Why* do you want to do ... well, whatever it is you're asking? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If the function `aFunction` is defined in the prototype you can refer to the outer variable on which the function was called using `this`.

Comment: I want it to be similar to charAt() native javascript function, which is used as: string.chartAt(0)

Comment: It would be more clear to have a "use case" and the need to do this, probably there might be other options than just changing the string to have a certain method by prototype or methor property for that value

Comment: Read about `prototype` in javascript

Comment: @AndreasKarps Keep in mind that extending built-in objects' prototype is bad practice. Same as defining global variable. It might cause name conflicts with another code or future standards. At least use `Object.defineProperty` to make this property non enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `String.prototype.aFunction` so that you can add a custom function `aFunction()` to the prototype of `String` such that it can be invoked by a string variable. Also `this.toString()` inside the prototype function will give you the value of the `x` variable (calling string)

```js
var x = 'testString'
var y = 'anotherstring'
var z = 0

String.prototype.aFunction = function(y, z){
  console.log(this.toString());
  return y+z;
}
var result = x.aFunction(y, z);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: *"how can I get and use the value of x in the function aFunction?"*

Comment: great, thanks, found a similar post that also helped

Comment: @AndreasKarps cool. I have updated the answer check it out

Comment: @deceze thanks for pointing that