# How can I get variables before a dot?

Tags: javascript

I want to get variables before a dot like this:

```js
"hello".myFunction();
```

I want to get "hello".
I tried using this code and I thought that this is obviously not gonna work.

```js
function myFunction(){
  return value;
}
```

But it doesn't work.
I always getting this error.

> TypeError: "hello world".myFunction is not a function. (In '"hello world".myFunction()', '"hello world".myFunction' is undefined)

Comment: `hello` is a string which does not have `myFunction` method on it, why not simply pass `myFunction('hello')` and use it in `myFunction`

Comment: `"hello"` is not a variable, it's a string literal, resulting in a string value. Please provide a better explanation of what you are trying to do. If generally you want to get a reference to the object you are calling a method on, you can do that via `this`: `({foo: 42, bar() { console.log(this); }).bar()`

Comment: I want to use it like `toUpperCase()`. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`String.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) and `this` keyword

```js
String.prototype.myFunction = function() {
  document.body.innerText = this
}

"hello".myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it like toUpperCase(), try this.

```
String.prototype.myFunction = function() {
  return this.toUpperCase();
}

"abc".myFunction() // Evaluates to ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now you are using a string and calling a user defined function on string. That can be accomplished by prototype overriding. 
So you can add one function on String object and use it. check this link....

[Add method to string class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/add-method-to-string-class)

```
String.prototype.myFunction = function(a){

   return a;
}

"hello".myFunction("Done");
```