# Function that returns the opposite letter

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that returns alternating characters, so for instance:

```
"hello world".toAlternatingCase() === "HELLO WORLD"
"HELLO WORLD".toAlternatingCase() === "hello world"
"HeLLo WoRLD".toAlternatingCase() === "hEllO wOrld"
```

Here is my try

```
const alternatingCase = function (string) {
  let newword = "";

  for (i = 0; i<string.length; i++) {
     if (string.charAt(i).toUpperCase())
    {
    newword+= string.charAt(i).toLowerCase()
    }

   else 
   {
   newword+=string.charAt(i).toUpperCase()
   }
  }
  return newword  
}
```

When invoked, the function unfortunately only returns the string itself, not sure what I'm doing wrong though, thanks very much for reading or even helping out!

Comment: Hey check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/add-method-to-string-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've done the compression wrong

checkout this

```js
function alternatingCase(string) {
  let newword = "";

  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
     const c = string.charAt(i);
     if (c === c.toUpperCase()){
        newword += c.toLowerCase()
     } else {
       newword += c.toUpperCase()
     }
  }
  
  return newword;
}

console.log(alternatingCase("TesT"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the caracter is uppercase and take then lower case.

Don't forget to declare all variables.

This approach uses a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) where a condition is used to return two different expressions.

```js
const alternatingCase = function(string) {
    let newword = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        let character = string[i];
        newword += character === character.toUpperCase()
            ? character.toLowerCase()
            : character.toUpperCase();
    }
    return newword;
}

console.log(alternatingCase('Test'));
```

If you really need to use the function as prototype of string, you need to assign the function to `String.prototype`and the wanted method. For this you need to address [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), to get the value of the string.

```js
String.prototype.alternatingCase = function() {
    let newword = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        let character = this[i];
        newword += character === character.toUpperCase()
            ? character.toLowerCase()
            : character.toUpperCase();
    }
    return newword;
}

console.log('Test'.alternatingCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to update is your condition to `if (string.charAt(i) === string.charAt(i).toUpperCase())`. You have to compare your `uppercase` letter to `original` letter.

```js
const alternatingCase = function(string) {
  let newword = "";

  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string.charAt(i) === string.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
      newword += string.charAt(i).toLowerCase()
    } else {
      newword += string.charAt(i).toUpperCase()
    }
  }
  return newword
}

console.log(alternatingCase("HeLLo WoRLD"));
```