# What does prototype mean here in the jQuery source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As an example, copied from jQuery 1.2.6:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    init: function( selector, context ) {
        // Make sure that a selection was provided
        selector = selector || document;
        ..........
    },
};
```

I have read some posts here like [JavaScript: What are .extend and .prototype used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781373/javascript-what-are-extend-and-prototype-used-for) and know a prototype can be used in a subclass to extend some methods.

But I cannot understand the usage in the above snippet from jQuery.

Are there any canonical documents describing the prototype?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the tag info references. In particular I suggest you [this article](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html) from Eloquent JavaScript, and [this one](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1) from the ECMAScript language specification.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

All objects have a `prototype` property. It is simply an object from which other objects can inherit properties. The snippet you have posted simply assigns an object with some properties (such as `init`) to the `prototype` of `jQuery`, and aliases `jQuery.prototype` to `jQuery.fn` because `fn` is shorter and quicker to type. If you forget about jQuery temporarily, consider this simple example:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    alert(this.name + " says hello");
};

var james = new Person("James");
james.sayHello(); // Alerts "James says hello"
```

In this example, `Person` is a *constructor* function. It can be *instantiated* by calling it with the `new` operator. Inside the constructor, the `this` keyword refers to the instance, so every instance has its own `name` property.

The `prototype` of `Person` is shared between all instances. So all instances of `Person` have a `sayHello` method that they *inherit* from `Person.prototype`. By defining the `sayHello` method as a property of `Person.prototype` we are saving memory. We could just as easily give every instance of `Person` its own copy of the method (by assigning it to `this.sayHello` inside the constructor), but that's not as efficient.

In jQuery, when you call the `$` method, you're really creating an instance of `jQuery.prototype.init` (remember that `jQuery.fn === jQuery.prototype`):

```
return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, rootjQuery);
```

And if you look at `jQuery.fn.init`:

```
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

So really, you're creating an instance of `jQuery` which has access to all the methods declared on `jQuery.prototype`. As discussed previously, this is much more efficient than declaring those methods on each instance of `jQuery`.

Comment: Is **jQuery.fn** only a name?Does it have relation to so-called **namespace**?

Comment: `fn` is a property of the `jQuery` object (just like `prototype` is just a property of the `jQuery` object). The value of both the `fn` property and the `prototype` property is a reference to a single object.

Comment: thanks! What is **jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;** for?

Comment: @liamxu - You're welcome :) That line causes `jQuery.fn.init` to inherit all of the methods declared as properties of `jQuery.fn`. So when you get an instance of `jQuery.fn.init` (which is what you get by calling `jQuery`), it has access to all the usual jQuery methods that you would expect it to. Does that make sense?

Comment: I saw **new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery )**, why it can call the *init* method of jQuery.prototype? You said **jQuery.fn.init** is a class?In my opinion, **new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery )** should call its constructor.

Comment: `jQuery.fn.init` is a class (as far as "classes" go in JavaScript anyway). When you call it with the `new` operator, it creates a new instance of `jQuery.fn.init`. It's quite confusing, because `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` is `jQuery.fn`, so there's an infinite cyclical reference.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Great answer and follow up.  Thanks!

Comment: Mmmmm, The JQuery force is strong in this one.