# Why javascript Function prototype need to fix constuctor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor

for example. i usually see the JQuery source or other javascript framework source when they assign the object to the function's prototype, they usually do so:

```
function A(){}
A.prototype = {
    constructor: A,
    // ....
}
```

i am really confused about that. I mean why it have to do so?

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140292/what-does-prototype-mean-here-in-the-jquery-source-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, all normally-created functions have a `prototype` property which is, initially, an object created by the JavaScript engine with one property: `constructor`, which refers back to the function. So for

```
function A() {
}
```

...we know that, initially, `A.prototype.constructor === A`. This also means that objects created via `new A` will inherit `constructor`, and so:

```
var o = new A();
console.log(o.constructor === A); // true
```

But if you *replace* the object on the `prototype` property with something else, as your code snippet does, then the new thing's `constructor` property (which it inherits) is pointing to the wrong function unless you fix it:

```
function A() {
}
A.prototype = {}; // Replace the object
var o = new A();
console.log(o.constructor === A);      // false
console.log(o.constructor === Object); // true
```

Oops. That's why the snippet you've quoted is setting `constructor` on the object it's assigning to `A.prototype`.

But what's the point of the `constructor` property? Actually, nothing in the JavaScript specification ever *uses* that property; the only mention of it relates to the above, making sure that the initial object on the `prototype` property has `constructor` referring back to the function.

But some code (including some libraries) may assume that `constructor` is set "properly" (e.g., the way it is by default by the JavaScript engine), and may try to use it to figure out what an object "is" (although there's usually little if any reason to do that; in the rare case when you actually care, `instanceof` is usually the better way to check, as it allows for derived objects). Or they may try to use it in cloning operations, although as of ES5 there are better ways.

In any case, since there is (rare) code out there that may rely on the `constructor` property being set as it is by the JavaScript engine, well-behaved code replacing the `prototype` property entirely sets `constructor` the same way the JavaScript engine does, just in case.

In practice, it's *very common* for people to leave out that step when replacing the object on the `prototype` property, and so relying on `constructor` in new code is not best practice. But being sure you set `constructor` properly probably still is, just in case.